# Should an if-statement end with else in a function that asserts the values

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, methods

Suppose I have a function with a variable `drinks` whose values might be extended later on:

```
def what_to_drink(drinks):
    assert drinks in ['coffee','tea'], "Invalid 'drink' value. Please choose between 'coffee' or 'tea'."

    if drinks == 'coffee':
        print("I don't drink coffee, I drink tea my dear")
    elif: drinks == 'tea':
        print("I am an English man in New York")
```

Since the values for drinks might be extended, it seems to make sense to use `elif` instead of `else`. However, should the if-statement end with an else-statement? This seems redundant since the assert operator already serves as a gatekeeper for unwanted values. However, without the else-statement, the logic seems incomplete.

Comment: You should never rely on an `assert` for logic in the first place.

Comment: Why shouldn't I rely on `assert` for logic?

Comment: If an `assert` statement is actually executed depends on the interpreter mode. It might all work nicely in dev and staging, and suddenly in production where your Python runs in optimized mode, the line is skipped and you have a hard to find bug.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit:** As pointed out, by [@user2390182](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/user2390182) and [@TedKleinBergman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6486738/ted-klein-bergman), the usage of `assert` in the first place is arguably a bigger thing to consider than whether
> an else is useful when the logic doesn't allow it to get there.
> However, I assume here that you have decided to use `assert` yourself,
> and will be using it in a way that respects the `assert` consistently.

**Facts:**
As `drinks` always has to be an element of your list, as long as you always have an `elif` allocated for each item in the list, you will never reach an `else` and therefore it is unnecessary.

**Opinion:**
It terms of correct practice what to do in this situation, it's really down to personal choice. The online consensus is often "less code is better" but if it makes your code clearer, or if you're likely to be changing the list of drinks often, it may make more sense to add it as a catch all, to stop anything breaking during your development. As with a lot of decisions like this, you have to take it on a case by case basis, and decide which you think is better in this situation.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman `assert` would raise an error if the input from the user is not within the designated list, so if the input was not there, the program will not continue. Therefore, I don't believe the `else` would be reached, unless as I say, there's an item in the list that does not have an `elif` for it.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman See my edit, didn't consider mentioning the use of asset in the first place, thanks!